# How to convert Unicode char to “Unicode HEX Position” in Arduino

Tags: programming, c, communication

How to convert Unicode char to "Unicode HEX Position" in Arduino or C

i will share a picture here :

[image]

for example in JavaScript you can do that with `charCodeAt();` ! this function will return exactly the char-code and then you can convert it to hex!

for example in JavaScript i can do that like this to return exact table value

```
 var inpString = 'س';
    var myChar=0;
    var output = 0;
    myChar = inpString.charCodeAt(0);
    output = (ToHex((myChar&0xff00)>>8 )) + (ToHex( myChar&0xff ));
    
    function ToHex(i)
    {
        var sHex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        var Out = "";
        Out = sHex.charAt(i&0xf);
        i>>=4;
        Out = sHex.charAt(i&0xf) + Out;
        return Out;
    }
 alert(output);
```

So how can i do that in Arduino ? its using to send unicode char in PDU mode in Arduino
i just need to convert unicode char like this -> 'س' to correct Unicode HEX Position that i shared in the picture above

for example 'س' is 0633 or 'A' is 0041 or 'ب' is 067E

Comment: Or simply `console.log("س".charCodeAt(0).toString(16))`.

Comment: please do not post at multiple locations ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62878287/how-to-convert-unicode-char-to-unicode-hex-position-in-arduino-or-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, C++ makes no difference between a character and its
code point. Thus, `'A'`, `0x41` and `65` are just different ways of
writing the same number.

Note, however, that the `char` type is intended to hold ASCII only. For
everything else, you may try using [wide characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character). For example, the
program

```cpp
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    wchar_t c = L'س';
    Serial.println(c, 16);
}

void loop() {}
```

outputs `633` on the serial port. Note the second argument to
`Serial.println()` which specifies base 16. Default is to print
numbers in decimal.

Beware that the representation of wide characters is implementation
defined, and the avr-libc doesn't provide support for manipulating them
or strings made with them. If you want to transmit them, you will also
have to decide for yourself how to break them down into a sequence of
bytes, as that's the only thing a serial port (or I2C, or SPI for that
matter) can transmit. UTF-8 is the most popular choice. I doubt wide
characters are popular in embedded systems at all.

Comment: its working, you are amazing thank you so much

Comment: so the difference to the sketch in my answer is the encoding of the source code versus the encoding of Serial Monitor.

Comment: @Juraj: The encoding of the source code is irrelevant to my answer as long as the dev environment is consistent (same encoding used by the editor and assumed by the compiler): the compiler initializes `c` with the code point of the character the editor shows between the quotes. It is basically equivalent to writing `wchar_t c = 0x633`, but in a way that hopefully makes more sense to the programmer. As soon as the program does I/O with non-ASCII characters, it will have to make a decision about the character encoding it is going to use.

Answer (score 0):

This will read and print unicode characters from/to Serial Monitor and print their HEX codes. Please set the line ending in Serial Monitor to NL and confirm the entered character with Enter.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char buff[4];
    int l = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buff, sizeof(buff) - 1);
    if (l > 0) {
      buff[l] = 0;
      Serial.println(buff);
      Serial.print(buff[0], HEX);
      if (l > 1) {
        Serial.print(buff[1], HEX);
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer , this code print -> D8B3 for -> 'س' , Not 0633 ! 

but its working correct for ascii character

Comment: 1. If `buff[0]` is less than 16, you would have to zero pad. 2. This program assumes the serial monitor sends characters as [UCS-2BE](http://justsolve.archiveteam.org/wiki/UCS-2), which is not the case. Like almost everything nowadays, it uses UTF-8 for input and output.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, my sketch doesn't assume anything. it prints the hex values and I know it is UTF-8. and visible characters have codes > 0x10

Comment: The question is about printing the _code point_ (not the _code units_!) of a character in hex. Your sketch prints the hex values of _pairs of bytes_, concatenated. The way they are concatenated embeds the implicit assumption that these bytes represent 16-bit numbers transmitted in big endian order. Considering these 16-bit numbers as equivalent to code points is only valid if the characters are transmitted as UCS-2.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to output Unicode chars is to use Octal equivalents in the string you are printing.
e.g.

```
Serial.print("\342\204\211");
```

will output ℉ provided the receiver has  font for that unicode.

[Using Non-ASCII chars in Arduino](https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ArduinoProgramming/Languages/index.html)
has a .jar file that converts between Unicode chars, \u... strings and Octal

Hex \x.. is not used because C compilers can get confused if the next character after the two hex digits is 'a' to 'f'. Using octal avoids this problem. The GCC compiler used by Arduino also does not accept all unicode sequences such as \u0020
[image]